# Combine WHERE IN with inner GROUP BY query

Tags: soql

I have the following query:

```
select
    Id,
    Name,
    Source_ID__c
from
    Account
where
    Source_ID__c in (
        select
            Source_ID__c
        from
            Account
        group by
            Source_ID__c
        having
            count(Id) > 1
    )
```

It returns this error:

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
Source_ID__c FROM Account GROUP BY Source_ID__c HAVING
^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:117
expecting a right parentheses, found 'GROUP'
```

Running just the inner query works fine. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure about this particular error but in general you can't use aggregate queries in inner queries. I could not find a dedicated article in Salesforce docs but google for `only root queries support aggregate expressions` error.

Comment: Thank you that's probably the issue then. Do you have any idea how this could be written differently?

Comment: Do I understand properly that you would like to query only these accounts that have duplicate Source_ID__c?

Comment: Yes exactly. Thanks!

Comment: You could first query aggregate query, save results in a var and use to filter second query. Note that you cannot fetch more than 2000 aggregate results.